# React setInterval with useEffect not stopping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am basically trying to count from 0 to 100 at a specific speed.

so, I have the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setProgress((progress) => progress + 1);
        if (progress === 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 16);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
console.log(progress);
```

Now when I load my component, in the console the count does not stop, it keeps going over 100. How do I stop it when the progress reaches 100?

Comment: when are you expecting it to stop?

Comment: @kevin Probably after ~1600ms.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, but it could also be when the component unmounts since he's clearing the interval in 2 places.. I wanted clarification on that

Comment: I am expecting it to end after progress reaches 100

Comment: Log `process` from inside the interval handler.

Comment: hmm ya progress is always 0, but if i log it outside useEffect its counting up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you console log the `progress` value inside the useEffect you can see why it is not stopping.
try something like this to get it working:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setProgress(progress => progress + 1);
    }, 16);
    if (progress === 100) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [progress]);
console.log(progress);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  let interval = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((progress) => progress + 1);
    }, 16);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (progress === 100) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    }
  }, [progress]);

  console.log(progress);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my take. Using ref and 2 useEffects. https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-pine-5xntw?file=/src/App.js:0-639